# Xcode 4.5 4.6 View Controller Lifecycle results in older UIViewController being Zombied

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.5, uialertview

I have an app I haven't touched in a while, and have decided to update it.  When I run it in Xcode 4.6 I get a Bad Access error and as I profile it my my ViewController Alertview is the object that is called and eventually left as an NSZombie.

I am uncertain if the problem is the alertview or the viewcontroller it calls.

Here is the Action tied to a button that calls the alert view:

```
- (IBAction)newGame:(id)sender {
timerIsActive = NO;
//UIImage *pauseImage = [UIImage imageNamed:rndImage];
UIImageView *pauseView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)] autorelease];
pauseView.image = gameImage;
[self.view addSubview:pauseView];

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Would you like to reset the game?"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Game"
                                                message:message 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Back to Game" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"New Game", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[Flurry logEvent:@"New Game"];
```

}

The alert view is as follows:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
timerIsActive = NO;
NSString *buttonString = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if( [buttonString isEqualToString:@"Main Menu"] ){

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
} else if( [buttonString isEqualToString:@"View Board"] ){

} else if( [buttonString isEqualToString:@"Back to Game"] ){

    timerIsActive = YES;
    NSArray *arr =[self.view subviews];
    [[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:([arr count]-1)] removeFromSuperview];


} else if( [buttonString isEqualToString:@"New Game"] ){

    seconds = 120;
    board.numOfLetters = 0;
    board.currentWordLetters = nil;
    board.currentString = nil;
    board.words = nil;
    board.letters = nil;


    //[boardView release];
    //[board release];
    [timer invalidate];
    [self release];

    ViewController *viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    viewController.gameSize = self.gameSize;
    self.view = viewController.view;

}
```

Comment: NSZombies are only created with they are enabled as an environment variable.  This should never be the case in production code.

Comment: Not in production.  In Profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the problem area:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController.gameSize = self.gameSize;
self.view = viewController.view;
```

You are creating a view controller that is autoreleased, you are assigning its view to `self.view`, then the method ends.  At this point, nothing is owning the view controller, so it is free to be deallocated.

This is not the correct way to transition from one view controller to the next.  You don't just pass views around from one view controller to the next, you should have something that manages your view controllers.

Without knowing more about your application architecture, it's difficult to suggest corrective action, but consider telling whichever object is in charge of your game lifecycle (I'm guessing in your case it's your app delegate?) that a new game should be started.  That object will hold the current view controller, and when it receives that message, it should create the new view controller - and own it.

You should read Apple's documentation about how to structure an application, particularly the parts about the roles view controllers play and the ownership rules for Cocoa.

Comment: Duh.  I was tying to work with something that has worked,but now that I have to upgrade it, the new xcode and iOS did not let this slip by.  I do manage the view stack from the appdelegate, and now that you've refreshed my memory, I am in there and see where the views are stacked.  Thanks!